# Populate Model class from Data in Backend

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, sqldatareader

I have a database that has two tables as follows, Please ignore the data but the format looks as follows

[image]

Now I have a Model class that is constructed as follows

```
public class FamilyModel
    {

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<FamilyModel> FamilyList { get; set; }
        public FamilyModel()
        {
            FamilyList = new List<FamilyModel>();
        }
}
```

Now all I want is to get data from the two tables and populate the list.

So I have a stored procedure that returns data as follows

[image]

So I have written some code to populate the above class. But it dosent work. I get a count of 5 when I debug. I want the count to be 2 and when expanded I want something like FamilyA ->{Nick, Tom, Pam}.. FamilyB->{Harry} and so on. Please help fixing this code.

```
    public static FamilyModel familyData()
            {
                //FamilyModel fml = new FamilyModel();
                //fml.FamilyList = new List<FamilyModel>();
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0; AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Families.mdf; Integrated Security=True; Connect Timeout=30;"))
                {
                    con.Open();
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_GetFamilies", con);
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    while (dr.Read())                                                             {                                                          
                        FamilyModel fm = new FamilyModel();                    
                        fm.Name = dr["FamilyName"].ToString();
                        foreach (var item in dr["ChildName"].ToString())
                        {
                            if (Convert.ToInt32(dr["id"]) == Convert.ToInt32(dr["FID"]))
                            {
                                fm.FamilyList.Add(new FamilyModel() { Name = dr["ChildName"].ToString() });
                            }
                        }

                    }
 return fm;
                }

    }
```

Comment: `List<FamilyModel>` should be a `List<Person>` rather.

Answer (score 0):

You need to distinguish between a new row in the data set and a new `FamilyModel`.  One way to do this is to declare a list of models, then look up the "right" one before you add the current child row:

```
var rootModel = new FamilyModel();
rootModel.Name = "root";

// ... Set up data reader ...

while (dr.Read()) 
{
    //This requires support for the Id in your FamilyModel:
    var id = (int)dr["Id"];
    //You could also use ".Single(...)" here
    var fm = rootModel.FamilyList.Where(x => x.Id == id).First();
    if (fm == null) 
    {
        fm = new FamilyModel();
        fm.Name = dr["FamilyName"].ToString();
        rootModel.FamilyList.Add(fm);
    }
    fm.FamilyList.Add(new FamilyModel() { Name = dr["ChildName"].ToString() });
}
```

For each row in your database query, you'll:

1. Try to look up that family in your list
2. If you don't find one, create a new one.  Add it to your top-level list.
3. Add the child name as a sub-element of the "current" family.

Comment: Dosent work Brian. I added a property for id. But please have a look at 

var fm = rootModel.FamilyList.Where(x => x.Id == id) returns IEnumerable so fm=new FamilyModel is not valid right.

Comment: Good point.  I've edited my answer to address that.  Code written in the Stackoverflow editor misses details like that sometimes :)

Comment: Thanks Brian il give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some source code that should get the right idea across. Below it, I've included some explanation for what's going on.

```
using Dapper;
public class FamilyModel
{
    public int Id { get; set;}
    public string FamilyName { get; set; }
    public List<Person> Members { get; set; } = new List<Person>();//Initializer for Auto-Property, C#6<= only
}
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set;}
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class DatabasePOCO
{
    public string FamilyName { get; set; }
    public string ChildName { get; set; }
    public int Fid { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set;}
}
void Main()
{
    using (IDbConnection conn = new SqlConnection("..."))
    {
        conn.Open();
        var raw = conn.Query<DatabasePOCO>("sp_GetFamilies",
        commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);//Could be dynamic, not typed
        var familyList = raw
        .GroupBy(x => x.Fid)
        .Select(x =>
        {
            var rawMembers = x.ToList();
            var fId = x.First().Fid;
            var fName = x.First().FamilyName;
            var members = rawMembers.Select(y => new Person 
            {
                Id = y.Id,
                Name = y.ChildName
            });
            return new FamilyModel
            {
                Id = fId,
                FamilyName = fName,
                Members = members.ToList()
            };
        });
        //Whatever else you want to do here
    }
}
```

1. Consider using [Dappper](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net). It is a great ORM that makes accessing data from database *really easy*. It's designed to work with SQL Server, but I've had success using Oracle too, and most other RMDBS systems will probably work.
2. Consider using [Slapper](https://github.com/SlapperAutoMapper/Slapper.AutoMapper). If you have control over your stored procedure, this can reduce a *lot* of the boilerplate code below.
3. If you use Dapper (I hope you do), you can play around with C# dynamic objects, or you can create a [POCO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/250001/poco-definition) to help get some type enforcement on your code.
4. Understand if you care about reference equality. The code I provided below does *not* enforce reference equality of objects. Reference equality, in my experience, doesn't buy you much and is a pain to enforce.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but my ultimate goal is to solve this problem
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38084429/binding-hierarchical-treeview-from-database
That is the reason why I am considering my own class structure as the model.

Comment: My suggestion to use Dapper/Slapper still holds (it'll help you when you have more complicated objects!) and in that link, there are distinct parent and child objects, but maybe I just don't see the subtlety. 
Anyway, good luck!